# How do getters work in nested objects when getting a property name from a nested object during object construction?

Tags: javascript, json, getter-setter, getter

I want to get a nested property name in an object during object construction.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the expected output: `'c'` from the nested object?

###### [Starting point: MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```js
const obj = {
  log: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  get latest() {
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
  }
};

console.log(obj.latest);
// Expected output: "c"
// Actual output: "c"
```

Confirmed. The above starting example works.

Now, I want to add nesting (`obj.level1`). This is where things fall apart.

###### Modification attempt 1: not working

```js
const obj = {
  level1: {
    log: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    get latest() {
      return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
    }
  }
};

console.log(obj.latest);
// Expected output: "c"
// Actual output: undefined
```

###### Modification attempt 2: not working

```js
const obj = {
  level1: {
    log: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    get latest() {
      return this.log[this.level1.log.length - 1];
    }
  }
};

console.log(obj.latest);
// Expected output: "c"
// Actual output: undefined
```

Comment: Can you please tell me about the environment where you are executing the code? I am asking this because, the above code in MDN docs working in browser and as per the docs, it supports almost all the browsers and nodejs.

Comment: You need to use `obj.level1.latest`, or not put the getter in the nested object but in `obj` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `latest` function exists on the `level1` depth. So the following works:

```js
console.log(obj.level1.latest)
```

However, if that's not your intention, you should write your object as such.

```js
const obj = {
  level1: {
     log: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  },
  get latest() {
    return this.level1.log.at(-1);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your modifications `obj` doesn't have `latest` getter. It's in child object `level1`, so just try logging `obj.level1.latest`.